# How to exclude zero from plot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm using a dynamic input variable `button_var_fir` for a dashboard via flexdashboard and shiny and hence, I can't subset the dataframe each time via e.g. `df$variable > value` or the like:

```
ggplot(df_scat, aes(!!input$button_var_fir, !!input$button_var_sec)) + 
    geom_boxplot(aes(fill= Gen_type), alpha = 0.5, alpha = 0.75) +
```

At the moment, the plot looks like

[image: img]

and as you can see, I would like to get rid of all those zeros.
They are present because I replaced NAs with zeros but however, in plots like this, I don't have to keep those zero values and it would look much better and more reasonable without.

Comment: Replace the zeros with NA.

Comment: kidding? :D ..will try it out..   edit: Yeah, I think it's working. So, actually, I was trying for 1-2 hours an issue I caused, more or less, on purpose...  thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You could subset your data with `which`:

`df_scat[which(df_scat$your_column > 0),]`

Here is an example:

```
ggplot(mtcars[which(mtcars$am>0),], aes(x=factor(am), y=mpg)) +
  geom_point()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Or by you could simply remove the zeroes with `subset(dataset, variable!= 0)` in your ggplot

Sample code:

```
ggplot(subset(mtcars,am != 0), aes(x=factor(am), y=mpg))+
  geom_point()
```

Plot:[image]